# adding nameplates or property tags to gear

Tags: used-equipment

How might I label my stuff (camera bodies, lenses, flashes) as belonging to me? I may want to sell the item again some day, so a sharpee is not a viable approach.

Comment: Label for what reason? Do you lend your stuff out, or get it mixed up with other people's gear? Do you need something visible, or would it suffice to simply record all your serial #s?

Comment: I'm not worried about getting mixed up. Just some theft deterrent and feel better when I travel.

Comment: I'm struggling to see how a label that is easily removable enough to allow you to sell the item it's attached to someday would act as a theft deterrent...

Comment: A clearly visible label doesn't have to *look* removable from a distance.

Answer (score 3):

I use a slightly different approach that I think is better. **I simply take a photo of my contact information and leave it on my memory card.** I keep one in the regular DCIM folder as well as one outside of it. Its simple, and I believe it to be effective although I've never proven so.

In reality the only thing I care about is the images I've captured on my memory card and have not yet downloaded. Accessories and bodies can be replaced(and easily since I have insurance on it all), but the images are a different story. I believe the approach I take will achieve exactly what I want; and that is get my memory card back to me if someone who finds it wants to do so.